# Django Query month wise with last 6 month

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to query and the group is the Order of the last 6 months.

and this is my models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(_("Created On"), auto_now_add=True)
```

and this is my method to parse month:

```
from django.db.models import Func
class Month(Func):
    """
        Method to extract month
    """
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = '%(function)s(MONTH from %(expressions)s)'
    output_field = models.IntegerField()
```

And this is my query:

```
        current_date = date.today()
        months_ago = 6
        six_month_previous_date = current_date - timedelta(days=(months_ago * 365 / 12))

        order = Order.objects.filter(
            created_on__gte=six_month_previous_date,
        ).annotate(
            month=Month('created_on')
        ).values(
            'month'
        ).annotate(
            count=Count('id')
        ).values(
            'month',
            'count'
        ).order_by(
            'month'
        )
```

In my database `order table`, there is only on entry:
So it is returning

```
[{'month': 10, 'count': 1}]
```

But i dont want like this, i want like these of last 6 month, if in one month, there is no sales, it should return the `count: 0`

Like thise bellow:

```
       [
            {'month': 10, 'count': 1},
            {'month': 9, 'count': 0}
            {'month': 8, 'count': 0}
            {'month': 7, 'count': 0}
            {'month': 6, 'count': 0}
            {'month': 5, 'count': 0}
        ]
```

Comment: A database works under the *closed world assumption*, so it will not insert rows with `0`. You can however post-process the list. Note that Django already *has* an `ExtractMonth` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database works under the *closed world assumption*, so it will not insert rows with `0`. You can however *post-process* the list.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

order = Order.objects.filter(
    created_on__gte=six_month_previous_date,
).values(
    month=Month('created_on')
).annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).order_by('month')

order = {r['month']: r['count'] for r in order}

month = now().month
result = [
    {'month': (m % 12)+1, 'count': order.get((m % 12) + 1, 0)}
    for m in range(month-1, month-8, -1)
]
```

Note that Django already *has* an [**`ExtractMonth`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractMonth).

Comment: I dont want to run a for loop, Do you have any alternative solution instead of for loop?

Comment: @howrecepes: well you strictly speaking already *are* running a `for` loop, since Django internally has loop mechanisms to read the result of the database. Furthermore this runs in *O(n)*, which thus in case of six months is only six iterations. You can of course "unwind" these in six instructions, which will likely take more time. Furthermore these are strictly speaking not `for` loops, but list and dictionary comprensions.